# 「もしかして」機能を実装したい

Tags: api

サイトの検索フォームに、ユーザーが入力したキーワードにたいして「もしかして○○?」というものを実装したいのですが、APIなどはあるのでしょうか。

理想としては、Google日本語入力の予測変換がそのまま使えるとよいのですが、探してみると予測変換ではなく、通常の変換しか取得できませんでした。

おすすめのapiなどがあれば教えていただけないでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

レーベンシュタイン距離という概念があります。
私が知っている範囲ではphpやpostgreSQLに実装されているので他にもきっとあるでしょう。
簡単にいうと、二つの文字列がどのくらい似ているか、という指標です。

Answer (score 2):

Google Suggest API というそのままの物がある様です。更にそれを手軽に使える様にした jQuery プラグイン [jquery.googleSuggest.js](https://github.com/haochi/jquery.googleSuggest) もある様です。

```js
$("#input1").googleSuggest({search: "web"});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/haochi/jquery.googleSuggest/master/jquery.googleSuggest.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input1" value="" />
```